# How to delete a commited patch from local git repository?

Tags: git, git-svn

I am a git beginner and I need to delete one local commit before preparing the final patch.
This is the list of my branches:

```
[me@myhost]$ git branch -l
  master
* devel
```

I did some fixes and committed the patches with {{{git commit -a}}} and now these are the patches I have:

```
[me@myhost]$ git log --pretty=oneline -3
dddb36d2124b221997f6fd0489ce4c8d4617fbc7 Patch3
78ca669b137be2d3602907b52d5d6c0eb8fefda2 Patch2
1f7453c62a674544a38df556f7e6ced245841fd7 Patch1
```

Now, let's say I want to remove the Patch3 which is not yet in the svn repository. Which is the cleanest/simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest and cleanest would be:

```
git reset --hard 78ca669b137be2d3602907b52d5d6c0eb8fefda2
```

Note that 78ca669b137be2d3602907b52d5d6c0eb8fefda2 is Patch2

Comment: I didn't see it was about removing Patch3 (I thought Path2, hence my rebase suggestion). +1

Comment: It looks like my git version (1.7.5.4) doesn't have rest command...Did you mean 'reset'?

Comment: @Cinquo - Sorry, didn't even realize the typo. Yes it is the `reset`. Updated.